# A1 was not declared in the scope

Tags: arduino-uno, sketch, mac-os, raspberrypi

I'm trying to put all my settings in a config.h file and then `#include` it in the Arduino sketch.

Here's what my config.h looks like:

**RobotConfig.h**

```
#ifdef BOT
    //hardware pins
    int motor1Pin = 9; //s0
    int motor2Pin = 10; //s1

    //pins for light
    int light2 = A4; 
    int light3 = A2; //right
    int light1 = A1; //left
```

And here's what .ino sketch looks like:

```
#define BOT
#include "RobotConfig.h"

void setup() {
  //Light INIT
  pinMode(light1, OUTPUT); //left light with motor1/s1 in front
  pinMode(light2, OUTPUT); //middle light with motor1/s1 in front
  pinMode(light3, OUTPUT); //right light with motor1/s1 in front
  ...
}
```

This compiles fine on my Mac but I'm trying to compile this on Raspberry Pi (Pi3 with new Jessie install with `sudo apt-get install arduino`) and get an error while doing so. The error says:

> A1 was not declared in the scope etc.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have an `#endif` in RobotConfig.h ?  If so, please edit your question to show it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RobotConfig.h needs to include Arduino.h in order to have those constants.